# Managing dependency across Upstart and SysV-style init.d script

Tags: 11.10, upstart, init.d

I have an Upstart job that must run before a SysV-style init.d script runs.
The init.d script is configured to be started in the runlevels 2, 3, 4 and 5 with priority 20.

What can I do to have the Upstart job to start earlier than the init.d script?

Comment: Useful reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has `/etc/init/rc.conf` starting on all runlevels. It calls `/etc/init.d/rc` with new runlevel as parameter. I don't think its possible to time your job to start per init.d script, but if you put your job starting on `starting rc` or `startup`, it has the best chances.

Comment: Note that 'start on starting rc' will also start every time you reboot or shut down. 'start on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]' is better. Also start on startup will start without networking, or writable filesystems, and so is probably not what youw ant.