# Upstart script that depends on init.d scripts?

Tags: upstart

I have an upstart script to start a custom nodejs app. The app depends on couchdb and elasticsearch. couchdb and elasticsearch provide init.d scripts for starting/stopping them. Is it possible to tell my upstart script that couchdb and elasticsearch are dependencies? I tried this in my upstart script but it does not seem to work:

start on (started couchdb and started elasticsearch)

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109516/managing-dependency-across-upstart-and-sysv-style-init-d-script ;)

Comment: I tried this: start on started rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] but it doesn't help. Elasticsearch wasn't started when my app started. So it appears there isn't a way for my upstart script to know if the services started by init scripts have already started?

Comment: well the only thing I know that would work is to create (or search for and install) upstart scripts for both elasticsearch and couchdb so you can use the "start on" option.

Comment: See if this answer is helpful! I found upstart script for both :D Untested code so you might need to tweak it for your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I know that would work is to create (or search for and install) upstart scripts for both elasticsearch and couchdb so you can use the "start on" option.

> Upstart script for couchdb

```
# couchdb v1.2.0
#
# Custom installation of CouchDB

description     "CouchDB v1.2.0, local"
console output

# start after all filesystems & network interfae are available
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

# set working directory
env COUCHDB_WD="/path/to/build-couchdb/build/bin"
export COUCHDB_WD

# required for erlang
env HOME="/home/user"
export HOME

script
  # modify PATH to hit local couchdb's working directory first
  PATH="$COUCHDB_WD:$PATH"
  #export PATH # not necessary inside script block
  #logger -t $0 "HOME='$HOME'"
  #logger -t $0 "PATH='$PATH'"
  # output couchdb logs to custom location
  #exec >>/home/user/couchdb_local.log 2>&1
  exec couchdb
end script
```

- edit the env to what you need;
- Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980900/how-to-get-custom-couchdb-to-run-as-upstart-job

> Upstart for elasticsearch

```
# ElasticSearch Service

description     "ElasticSearch"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn limit 10 5

env ES_HOME=/usr/share/elasticsearch/home
env ES_MIN_MEM=256m
env ES_MAX_MEM=2g
env DAEMON="${ES_HOME}/bin/elasticsearch"
env DATA_DIR=/data/elasticsearch/data
env CONFIG_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

console output

script
  if [ -f /etc/default/elasticsearch ]; then
    . /etc/default/elasticsearch
  fi

  su -s /bin/dash -c "/usr/bin/elasticsearch -f -Des.path.conf=$CONFIG_DIR -Des.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.path.work=$WORK_DIR" elasticsearch
end script
```

- Source: https://gist.github.com/rbscott/1052015
- Change the env dir to what you need.

Comment: I ended up just creating an init.d script instead. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: I think you're correct...I just created the init.d script for now as a band-aid due to time constraints.

Comment: That will work too but is a regression ;) Since 12.10 favors upstart I expected upstart to be the better option. But if you got it working with init script go for it  ;)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same question, and I also found a [different answer](https://serverfault.com/a/374481/133759). The author lists 4 options to accomplish this, of which *I* like the first one best:

Use `initclt emit myservice-started` to signal the completion of your dependent service's startup. In the linked answer, it is suggested to add this line to the end of the dependency service's `init.d` script, but I prefer a different method.
I like to create a new `inid.d` script named `myservice-started` that only contains a `start` section. Using the appropriate commenting style in the file's header, I declare that it depends on `$myservice` to be started. In the `start` section, I tell upstart about `myservice` being started. You can install it with `update-rc.d`.

I like this solution because it is not intrusive; if an update changes any of the existing `init.d` scripts, it won't affect these additional scripts. But remember that changes to your upstart scripts *are* required.

It might look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myservice-started
# Required-Start:    $myservice
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Short-Description: send upstart signal after starting myservice
# Description:       myservice needs to run before some upstart services can run
### END INIT INFO

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
    start)
        log_daemon_msg "Signaling myservice started..." "myservice-started"
        initctl emit myservice-started --no-wait
    ;;

    *)
        log_action_msg "Usage: /etc/init.d/myservice-started start"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Your upstart script waiting for myservice can listen for the `myservice-started` event:

```
start on myservice-started
```