# How to set sequence level using /etc/init config file?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I need to start my service after postgresql. I have /etc/init/my_service.conf file that fails to start on bootup because postgres is not online yet. PG has sequences S19 & K21. With init.d script I can do it by `sudo update-rc.d my_script start 20 2 3 4 5 . stop 20 0 1 6 .`
How to do it in config file?

UPD This is a good idea to use `start on`, but there is no postgres job in the list `initctl list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upstart script that depends on init.d scripts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280642/upstart-script-that-depends-on-init-d-scripts)

Comment: There is no postgres job in upstart jobs list...