# Run a script as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, scripts, services, init.d

I have installed elasticsearch . This is how I am running it currently.

```
cd /elasticsearch-6.3.1/bin
./elasticsearch
```

It is working fine. But, I want to run this program as a service. Like, I want to run it like,

```
sudo service elasticsearch restart
```

It should run the elasticsearch. I have tried to create a script in `/etc/init.d` , but it is not working. This is what I did,

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo vim elasticsearch
```

This is content in that file,

```
cd /elasticsearch-6.3.1/bin
./elasticsearch
```

What is the recommended way to achieve this ?

Comment: 14.04 ... upstart?  I normally create a .conf in /etc/init. Then reload config and start it.

Comment: upstart will be fine. can you please tell me

Comment: I just did. /etc/init/. (not init.d) That dir should be full of *.conf files you can use as an example.

Comment: Possibly related: [Upstart script that depends on init.d scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280642/upstart-script-that-depends-on-init-d-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Create an upstart script like the following

```
# ElasticSearch upstart script

description     "ElasticSearch service"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])

stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

respawn limit 10 30

# NB: Upstart scripts do not respect
# /etc/security/limits.conf, so the open-file limits
# settings need to be applied here.
limit nofile 32000 32000

setuid elasticsearch
setgid elasticsearch
exec /path/to/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -f -Des.default.config=/path/to/config/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch/ -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch/ -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch/ -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/path/to/config/
```

Replace the paths with the absolute paths in your case. Save this as `elasticsearch.conf` in `/etc/init/`

Also note that you're best off running elasticsearch as it's own user (hence the setuid and setgid lines)